# How to get values of Zend_registry from one controller to other controller in zend?

Tags: zend-framework

I use the following way to get Zend_registry value from one controller to another but didn't success.Should I need to initiate Zend_registry in bootstrap.php or other file that I can use it between two files or more.

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('variableName', 'value');
or
Zend_Registry::set('variableName', $value);

And this is how you get the value

$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->get('variableName');
or
Zend_Registry::get('variableName');
```

To get more then one array

```
$value = array("name" =>'pankaj',"post" =>'sendeveloper');                         
Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName = $value;

$value1 = array("name" =>'rahul',"post" =>'jndeveloper');                         
Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableTable = $value;

$value3 = array("name" =>'vonod',"post" =>'techdeveloper');                         
Zend_Registry::get('session')->variabletech = $value;
```

It seems to work only variableName not other. What i need to do ?

Comment: This has to work (of course only during single PHP call)

Comment: like I have application/controller/UserController.php -> here I declare an aray('name'=>abc,'age' =>10); How can I get this array in application/controller/CustomerController.php

Comment: Are you looking to access the value across requests, or are you reading the value in the second controller in the same request? Another question would be is the information you are accessing the details of the currently logged in user?

Comment: There is an error replace `variableTable = $value;` by `variableTable = $value1;` and same thing with `variabletech ` add `3` to `value`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I use `Zend_Registry` **and** `Zend_Session_Namespace`.

In the bootstrap:

```
protected function _initSession()
{
    Zend_Registry::set('session', new Zend_Session_Namespace("doydoy44"));
}
```

And in `UserController`:

```
$value = array("name" =>'pankaj',"post" =>'developer'); 

Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName = $value;
```

and in `CustomerController`:

```
var_dump(Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName);
```

Comment: I have application/controller/UserController.php -> here I declare an aray('name'=>abc,'age' =>10); How can I get this array in application/controller/CustomerController.php

Comment: I want to set value in UserController and get value in CustomerController.php

Comment: The set value is with `Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName = $value; ` and the get value is with `Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName; `

Comment: But I see both time you use get function and acc to me to declare variable will use set function and for get value will use get().
So protected function _initSesssion() initialize zend_registry. Am i right ?

Comment: @smartdeveloper: In `UserController ` try this : `Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName = $your_array;` and in `CustomerController` try this : `var_dump(Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName);`

Comment: In the registry, I put the session, and in the controllers, i get the session and with this session, i set the variable with `$session->mavariable= $variable` and I get the variable with `$variable = $session->mavariable`;

Comment: UserController.php $value = array("name" =>'pankaj',"post" =>'developer');
       Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName = $value;
CustomerController.php         $values = Zend_Registry::get('session')->variableName; 
        echo "this is array format";
        print_r($values);
Bootstrap.php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initApp() {
       

        
    protected function _initSession()
    {
    Zend_Registry::set('session', new Zend_Session_Namespace("doydoy44"));
    }

o/p : this is array format

Comment: if I declare and call in single file it works fine but not in diff files

Comment: @smartdeveloper: I add precision in the answer. I test it with 2 differents controllers and it's works for me, I recover the array in the second controller.

Comment: Its work fine but if I use more then one variableName. It didnot output.Give output only with variableName like I need variable variableGroup didn't work

Comment: Please check question : after To get more then one array

Comment: @smartdeveloper: I add comment to the question, visibly, there is an typo error in the variables names

Comment: @smartdeveloper: If it's solve your pb, please, validate this answser.